# using terraform template_file and s3 to bootstrap with s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, terraform, hcl

We are trying to keep bootstrapping user_data configuration files in S3. But we also have a need to variables and manage secrets for parts of the user data scripts. So my thought was to create a bucket, store our scripts, then use `template_file` from s3. Then shove that rendered template into the user_data for my `aws_launch_configuration`. However one does not simply do that.

when I check my aws console I see that user_data just comes up as the url for bucket files. Is there a way I can still accomplish this or is there a better way of pulling user_data from s3 while still being able to pass along variables?

Below is my current failed attempt; cut down for brevity.

```
# Create folder and upload bootstrap files
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "bootstrap_config" {
  for_each      = "${fileset(var.bootstrapConfigPath, "*")}"

    bucket        = "${aws_s3_bucket.bootstrap_bucket.id}"
    acl           = "private"
    key           = "${each.value}"
    source        = "${var.bootstrapConfigPath}/${each.value}"
    etag          = filemd5("${var.bootstrapConfigPath}/${each.value}")
}
.
.in another module...
.
data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = "${join("", list(var.bootstrap_bucket, "/config/user_data.sh"))}"
  vars = {
    _port         = "${var.port}"
    _allowed_cidr = "${var.allowed_cidr}"
  }
}
.
.
.
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "sample_thing" {
  name_prefix                 = "sample-${var.environment}"
  image_id                    = "${var.ami_id[var.aws_region]}"
  instance_type               = "${var.instance_type}"
  associate_public_ip_address = "${var.ispublic}"
  key_name                    = "${var.key_name}"
  security_groups             = ["${aws_security_group.instance.id}"]
  iam_instance_profile        = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.the_profile.arn}"
  user_data                   = "${data.template_file.user_data.rendered}"

  root_block_device {
    encrypted             = true

  }
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok figured this out. based on this blog [post](https://www.rover.com/blog/engineering/post/reading-external-configuration-terraform-using-s3-objects/)

what I've done is output the user_data script as data from the module that contains the bootstrapping bucket and objects. then imported that in the launch config and used it in my `template_file`

```
# Create folder and upload bootstrap files
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "bootstrap_config" {
  for_each      = "${fileset(var.bootstrapConfigPath, "*")}"

    bucket        = "${aws_s3_bucket.bootstrap_bucket.id}"
    acl           = "private"
    key           = "${each.value}"
    source        = "${var.bootstrapConfigPath}/${each.value}"
    etag          = filemd5("${var.bootstrapConfigPath}/${each.value}")
}

data "aws_s3_bucket_object" "boot_config" {
    bucket      = "${aws_s3_bucket.bootstrap_bucket.id}"
    key         = "user_data.sh"
    depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_object.bootstrap_config]
}

output "boot_config" {
  value = "${data.aws_s3_bucket_object.boot_config.body}"
}
.
.in another module...
.
data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = "${var.boot_config}" #<-Imported output variable
  vars = {
    _port         = "${var._port}"
    _allowed_cidr = "${var._allowed_cidr}"
  }
}
.
.
.
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "sample_thing" {
  name_prefix                 = "sample-${var.environment}"
  image_id                    = "${var.ami_id[var.aws_region]}"
  instance_type               = "${var.instance_type}"
  associate_public_ip_address = "${var.ispublic}"
  key_name                    = "${var.key_name}"
  security_groups             = ["${aws_security_group.instance.id}"]
  iam_instance_profile        = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.the_profile.arn}"
  user_data                   = "${data.template_file.user_data.rendered}"

  root_block_device {
    encrypted             = true

  }
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```